# jQuery start hover animation when mouse stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a sliding door style animation that as of now fires off when the mouse hovers over the box (my example is provided below). Rather than it firing off immediately when the mouse hovers over the div I actually want the hover animation to only happen when the mouse stops on the div, much like it does in the chrome web store when you stop the mouse on one of the app containers (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home)

My Current Example
http://jsfiddle.net/fvXgK/

EDIT: Just to clarify further , there would be multiple cells appearing on this page.

Thanks for any help you can provide!!

Comment: This any good for you? http://www.jquery4u.com/events/writing-mousestop-event-plugin-jquery/#.UA7GO6AcvAk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the hoverintent plugin of jquery.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: Awesome suggestion have a feeling I may go with this one.

Comment: Ended up going with this at end. Worked the smoothest with multiple cells.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to change your hover event. On hover get the mouse coordinates then start a timeout with maybe 50-100ms. Use the timeout to compare the current mouse coordinates with the original set of coordinates. If they are the same, and your animation has not been executed, then do the animation. This is just a rough idea of what you could try.

Edit: Also remember to make an on mouse out event that stops the timeout.

Comment: Yea I may try to implement this, after I test out some of the plug-ins mentioned. This seems like a really smart approach though, since I'm honesty wanting to avoid the use of a plug in.

Answer (score 2):

See this fiddle, easy to use:

http://jsfiddle.net/pbaXa/

Comment: Great suggestion the only problem is, it will still fire off after 1 second. I need it to hold off until the mouse completely stops moving.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I would do it... it's just easier: plain and simple:

```
$('.smallCell.slidedown').hover(function() {
    $(".overlay", this).delay(1000).queue(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-260px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 300
    });


    });
}, function() {
    $(".overlay", this).animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 300
    });
});
```

And this is also self explanatory: it will delay 1 second and queue your function.

Comment: All you've done is introduce a one second delay. What happens if I move my mouse over the div and then back out several times? OP wants to trigger the animation when the mouse stops moving.

Comment: upz, my bad! Reading it all once again, you're right. This won't work as he wants =( The "hover intent" should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setTimeout for this and comparing to a stored "hover state" of the element.
My example might not be the best way to store the hover state if you are using multiple cells, but the concept still stands.

```
var TIME_UNTIL_SLIDE = 1000;

var isHovering = false;
var hovertimer;

$('.smallCell.slidedown').hover(function() {
    isHovering = true;
    var $this = this;
    hovertimer = setTimeout(function(){
        if(isHovering) {
             $(".overlay", $this).stop().animate({
                top: '-260px'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 300
            });
        }
    }, TIME_UNTIL_SLIDE);

}, function() {
    isHovering = false;
    $(".overlay", this).stop().animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 300
    });
});
```

Shown at:
http://jsfiddle.net/fvXgK/16/

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, huge help! All seem like very good ways to approach it. Going to play around with a couple of them and see how it works out. I will be sure to mark the answer once I pick it. Thansks again!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this plugin:

http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event

Easy to use and the example is just right there!

Comment: Great suggestion! This one actually may be the one I go with looks like it will do exactly what I need with out adding to much over head. Although I was hoping to avoid the use of a plug-in.

Comment: hmmm I tried this and it's not working, do you see where there is an issue?  http://jsfiddle.net/fvXgK/

Comment: Sorry, I didnt check my mails.